# sed error while underscore is part of the search text

Tags: mysql, bash, sed

While executing the below statement,

```
sed -l 's,`144_com`.,,q' [file_name_144_com.sql]
```

which is an attempt to remove the EXACT text (which in this case if the database name which needs to be removed for migration)

```
`144_com`.
```

from a MySQL dump file I get the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unknown command: `_'
```

I have attempted to escape the underscore with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Underscore has no special meaning, it doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: Why do you have the filename in square brackets?

Comment: it is just an example filename

Comment: What version of `sed` are you using?

Comment: Why are you using `-l` ? And why is there a `q` at the end of your sub?

Comment: @Barmar did you attempt to execute the above statement? It has no escape, and yet still fails... that is the issue.

Comment: I'm assuming the `-l` in your question is supposed to be `-i`. Otherwise, there needs to  be a number after it. Also, the `q` at the end should be a `g`???

Comment: On Linux I get a usage message listing all the options because you're missing the number after `-l`. On OS X I get `bad flag in substitute command: 'q'`

Comment: -i is to search the filename. The tailing q was the core issue. Thanks @Barmar

Comment: The question has `-l` not `-i`. `-i` means to overwrite the file instead of writing the result to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
sed -i 's/`144_com`.//g' 144_com_dev.sql
```

resolved the issue. -l was a typo, the trailing q was as well. Been a long day!